# What sort of correlation is there between "Abkommen" as a noun and "abkommen" as a verb?

Tags: verb, noun

I am pretty sure that those who are studying German must have encountered the following verb and noun:

> das Abkommen (Agreement, pact)

and

> abkommen (to deviate)

I am pretty sure the above noun derived from the verb abkommen but I cannot correlate it with the verb! How come the meaning has changed just simply by turning the noun into the verb?

Comment: Side note: You can not use *abkommen* as verb alone. For example *ich komme ab* is unclear. You need to combine it with *von/vom* and a noun like in *ich komme vom Weg ab* or *vom Weg abkommen*. I think *abkommen* is because of that a *Gefügeverb* like *ich stecke* or *ich bringe*

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to the Grimms the **verb** *abkommen* was formerly also used in the meaning of "to agree with somebody on something":

> Endlich ist *mit einem abkommen* so viel als *überein kommen, fertig werden, sich vertragen, vergleichen*. <sup>[Grimm](http://woerterbuchnetz.de/DWB/?sigle=DWB&mode=Vernetzung&lemid=GA00756#XGA00756)</sup>

This was similarily used like the modern verb *übereinkommen* which also exists as a noun *Übereinkommen* (agreement, convention).

Therefore the noun *Abkommen* indeed is a direct derivation from the verb *abkommen* where one of the meanings of the verb is lost today.

Interestingly it is still possible to also derive a noun from the still valid other meanings (e.g. *Das Abkommmen von der Fahrbahn führte zur Kollision*) but we do not use this too often, probably to avoid confusion.

Another interesting side note on this is that another noun derivation from the verb *abkommen* was *[Abkunft](http://www.dwds.de/?view=1&qu=Abkunft)* which today is almost exclusively used in the meaning of *descent* but was at times also used as a synonym for *Abkommen*.

Answer (score 2):

That is very much interesting, because it's not clear at all, and even I stumbled when I saw your question.

According to the [German Wiktionary](http://de.wiktionary.org/wiki/Abkommen), the original meaning of the noun was *von einer (finanziellen) Schuld abkommen/lösen*, i.e. to pay back one's debt. This usage makes it clear, what you're deviating from.

A century later, the meaning of the noun had shifted from *a deal to clear debts* to a *deal* in general and further formalised to mean *treaty* of any kind.